# Trouble extracting some content from a webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a script using python along with BeautifulSoup library to scrape a certain content from a webpage. The content I'm interested in are located under `What does that mean` in that page.

[Link to that page](https://www.obd-codes.com/p0100)

To be more specific - the content I would like to parse:

> Everything under this title `What does that mean` except for the image.

This is what I've tried so far to grab that:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.obd-codes.com/p0100"

def fetch_data(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    [script.extract() for script in soup.select("script")]
    elem = [item.text for item in soup.select("h2:contains('What does that mean') ~ p")]
    print(elem)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fetch_data(link)
```

However, the way I've tried gives me almost everything from that page which is not I'm expecting.

***How can I get the content between `What does that mean` and `What are some possible symptoms` from the above page?***

PS I don't wish to do it using regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize `itertools.takewhile` ([official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)) function to accomplish what you want:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from itertools import takewhile

link = "https://www.obd-codes.com/p0100"

def fetch_data(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    [script.extract() for script in soup.select("script")]
    elems = [i.text for i in takewhile(lambda tag: tag.name != 'h2', soup.select("h2:contains('What does that mean') ~ *"))]
    print(elems)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fetch_data(link)
```

Prints:

```
['This diagnostic trouble code (DTC) is a generic powertrain code, which means that it applies to OBD-II equipped vehicles that have a mass airflow sensor. Brands include but are not limited to Toyota, Nissan, Vauxhall, Mercedes Benz, Mitsubishi, VW, Saturn, Ford, Jeep, Jaguar, Chevy, Infiniti, etc. Although generic, the specific repair steps may vary depending on make/model.', "The MAF (mass air flow) sensor is a sensor mounted in a vehicle's engine air intake tract downstream from the air filter, and is used to measure the volume and density of air being drawn into the engine. The MAF sensor itself only measures a portion of the air entering and that value is used to calculate the total volume and density of air being ingested.", '\n\n\n\n\xa0', '\n', 'The powertrain control module (PCM) uses that reading along with other sensor parameters to ensure proper fuel delivery at any given time for optimum power and fuel efficiency.', 'This P0100 diagnostic trouble code (DTC) means that there is a detected problem with the Mass Air Flow (MAF)\nsensor or circuit. The PCM detects that the actual MAF sensor frequency signal\nis not performing within the normal expected range of the calculated MAF value.', 'Note: Some MAF sensors also incorporate an air temperature sensor, which is another value used by the PCM for optimal engine operation.', 'Closely related MAF circuit trouble codes include:', '\nP0101 Mass or Volume Air Flow "A" Circuit Range/Performance\nP0102 Mass\nor Volume Air Flow "A" Circuit Low Input\nP0103 Mass\nor Volume Air Flow "A" Circuit High Input\nP0104 Mass or Volume Air Flow "A" Circuit Intermittent\n', 'Photo of a MAF sensor:']
```

Edit:

If you want only `<p>` tags directly after the `<h2>` tag, use `lambda tag: tag.name == 'p'`.

Comment: I can't take this `~ *` @Andrej Kesely. The way you applied that general sibling selector is awesomely nice.

Comment: Hi andrej!! Is it possible that I can rectify this `soup.select("h2:contains('Symptoms') ~ *")` selector to include small ***s*** and capital ***S*** so that it can recognise `symptoms` and `Symptoms` other than this`soup.select("h2:contains('symptoms'),h2:contains('Symptoms') ~ *")`?

Comment: @MITHU With CSS selector I'm afraid it's not possible, but you can do this: `[h2 for h2 in soup.select("h2") if 'symptom' in h2.text.lower()]`

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can achieve the same. Let your script keep going until it comes across this tag `h2`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.obd-codes.com/p0100"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
[script.extract() for script in soup.select("script")]
elem_start = [elem for elem in soup.select_one("h2:contains('What does that mean')").find_all_next()]
content = []
for item in elem_start:
    if item.name=='h2': break
    content.append(' '.join(item.text.split()))
print(content)
```